# Cannot convert type string to bool

Tags: c#

What's wrong with the syntax? Using the conditional operator with `Eval` to find the value so that I can set the visible attribute as `true` or `false`. Got the error message.

```
 <asp:image Visible='<%# (Eval("BasicCenterProgram").ToString() == "false") ? "true" : 
 "false"%>' runat="server" height="20" src="uncheckedbox.png" />
```

Any suggestions please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Visible` is a `Boolean`. Just condense it to this:

```
'<%# (Eval("BasicCenterProgram").ToString() == "false") %>'
```